# Get current time as string swift 3.0

Tags: swift, time, swift3, nscalendar

How to get current time as a **String** (not as Date)

date time format.

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: If you want time interval in seconds, why you need to convert to String first?  You can use DateFormatter to covert Date into String

Comment: Thanks. Just in my case I received only time in hh:mm a format as string. How can I get it in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format and convert into seconds

Comment: all you need to get the  timeIntervalSince1970 for now is `let timeIntervalSince1970  = Date().timeIntervalSince1970`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the way I figure it out.

```
   // Get today date as String

        func getTodayString() -> String{

                let date = Date()
                let calender = Calendar.current
                let components = calender.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: date)

                let year = components.year
                let month = components.month
                let day = components.day
                let hour = components.hour
                let minute = components.minute
                let second = components.second

                let today_string = String(year!) + "-" + String(month!) + "-" + String(day!) + " " + String(hour!)  + ":" + String(minute!) + ":" +  String(second!)

                return today_string

            }

        let today : String!

        today = getTodayString()
```

Comment: It's much better to use a `DateFormatter` than getting all of the date components and building your own string.

Comment: To get something even simpler, based on the use of textfield, as far as you link a Date Formatter, you can simply write `mytextfield.objectValue = Date()`.

Answer (score 21):

To get time as String you should use DateFormatter, something like this, sorry if there some mistakes, I wrote it right here

```
let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = Date()
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: timeIntervalSince1970 it is a property not a method

Comment: public var timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval { get }

    /// Return a new `Date` by adding a `TimeInterval` to this `Date`.