# Current time to string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to get some kind of current date/time info converted to string in one line of code in Swift?

Comment: formate please ?

Comment: Please show your tried code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-as-datetime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199635/get-current-time-as-string-swift-3-0

Comment: other formate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift/43434964#43434964

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please copy and paste relevant code into your question as text.

Comment: How is the code not relevant? You've posted a question about an error in your code. If you want help getting your code working then you should post your code as text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to read, not to mention they are harder to put into the question than simply copying and pasting the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the current date and time as a string, and you really don’t care about the time zone or the format in any way, this will do:

```
let nowString = "\(Date())"
```

Comment: @AndrewL. Its strange! Just to know why do you want the date string by this way?

Comment: @AndrewL. But `"\(Date())"` is not the timestamp. `"\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"` is timestamp.